# MySQL enum field insert by index

Tags: mysql, enums, insert

There is a simple mysql table 'mytable' with a column called 'fruit', which is a enum field contains 'apple', 'orange' and 'mango'.

We can access the index value of the enum with SELECT fruit+0 FROM mytable
But how can we insert the enum field by index instead of INSERT INTO mytable fruit VALUE 'apple' WHERE ...

I tried INSERT INTO mytable fruit+0 VALUE '1' WHERE ... but it doesn't work and couldn't find any related topics here or from net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `INSERT INTO mytable(fruit) VALUES(1);` should work.

You don't need any `fruit+0` conversion like in select.

Comment: This answer is correct. You can simply use the numeric index as the value; however, be aware that you will need to keep track of the indexes yourself in case you re-order the enum values. They are indexed starting at 0 so your first item is at index 0. I will up vote this answer, but OP, please be aware, this isn't the greatest thing to do in practice.

Comment: Thanks! it works now. @wilmoore, in fact, the index will be generate at the beginning of access and no re-order of the enum values except if mysql will re-order it automatically?

Comment: Warning: **ENUMs are 1-based**, at least in MySQL: _"The elements listed in the column specification are assigned index numbers, beginning with 1. The index value of the empty string error value is 0."_ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

enums are specifically designed to remove the need to know index values. By using index values you're specifically going against the reason enums exist.

If you don't want to use the enum values for insertion, then I'd suggest splitting the fruit names off into a seperate table, and make your mytable.fruit a foreign key pointing at this new fruit table. Then you're inserting an ID value instead of 'apple'.

Comment: thanks for your answer and your explaination. i totally agree with you. but i want to know if there is a way doing that?